# In PHP how do i write: IS NOT SMALLER THAN

Tags: php

For example: a is not smaller than b

How do i write this ?

Comment: If a is not smaller than b, it must be equal or greater than.

Comment: No reason to down-vote this question, just because it is simple

Comment: Are you a programmer or tester?

Answer (score 11):

```
if ($a >= $b) 

if !($a < $b)
```

Comment: 2nd row gives you a Parse Error - at least in PHP 5.3.1

Comment: As below, 2nd line should be enclosed in (), eg if (!($a < $b))

Answer (score 8):

Having an exclamation point outside of the condition causes a syntax error, doesn't it?

`if(!($a < $b))`

"IF NOT A SMALLER THAN B"

Makes the most linguistic sense compared to their question.

Comment: that is syntactically correct, the ! just inverts the expression

Answer (score 4):

If a is not smaller than b, a is either greater than or equal to b so:

```
$a >= $b
```

Answer (score 4):

```
!($a<$b)
```

Or *simply*

```
$a>=$b
```

Answer (score 2):

a >= b

Assuming that a and b are guaranteed to be comparable.

Comment: Well i need this as i wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $a >= $b ) {
    echo $a . " is not smaller than " . $b;
} else {
    echo $a . " is smaller than " . $b;
}
```